# Why does google chrome prompts to "select a certificate to authenticate yourself"

Tags: google-chrome, nginx

I have an application running in a tomcat server which is behind a NginX which has a proper certificate. When I try to access this app using Chrome in Mac OS X, I get the "select a certificate to authenticate yourself" pop-up in the browser.

I want to avoid this. To do it, I need to know why this occurs. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

That's because your Tomcat server requires TLS client authentication to established the connection. You should change the Tomcat server configuration to disable TLS client authentication.