# Prevent browser from prompting for client certificate for IIS app

Tags: iis, client-certificates

We have an application deployed to IIS and every time we connect to it, we get the following browser prompt:

> Select a certificate to authenticate yourself to *sitename*

[image: Select a Certificate prompt]

We do not have a reason to challenge for a client certificate and seems like this setting was introduced by mistake

How can we remove it?

**Research**:

- This question on [How can I prevent browsers from prompting Users for a Client Certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54292661/1366033) looks similar, but doesn't have an answer yet, and also is about setting this up on [kestrel-http-server](/questions/tagged/kestrel-http-server)
- This question on [Browser is not prompting for a client certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15014288/1366033) is for how to *make sure* there is a prompt, and didn't provide enough hints as to how to prevent one

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Open IIS and navigate to your web site or application and go to the SSL settings

   [image: IIS Settings > SSL Settings]
2. Set the Client Certificate setting to "Ignore"

   [image: SSL Settings > Client Certificates]

   Both 'Accept' and 'Require' will both challenge for a client side cert
3. Recycle your app pool and re-launch your browser to test

**Note**: SSL settings are inherited from your Site > Application, so you may need to apply these SSL Settings at multiple levels

**Further Reading**:

- [Why does google chrome prompts to "select a certificate to authenticate yourself"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26382109/1366033)
- [How to prevent browser from prompting for a client certificate and allow the IIS to accept it (not require it)?](https://serverfault.com/q/667285/176522)